# Invalid XPath expression with calendar day

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use selenium to select the calendar day from an x-path expression. I'm fairly confident the x-path is correct, but clearly, something is not right.

[image]

```
    cal_day = ['1'] 
    for day in cal_day:
        expression = f"//div[@class='datepicker-days']/table/tbody/tr/td/[contains(@class, 'day') and text() = '{day}']"
        reverse_day_select = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(expression)[0]
        reverse_day_select.click()
```

After performing the script, i receive the following error in the command prompt:

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@class='datepicker-days']/table/tbody/tr/td/[contains(@class, 'day') and text() = '1'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@class='datepicker-days']/table/tbody/tr/td/[contains(@class, 'day') and text() = '1']' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need little correction.

```
expression = f"//div[@class='datepicker-days']/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class, 'day') and text() = '{day}']"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It's the little things that matter.